# vue js error when adding bonus items to another item

Tags: laravel, vue.js

good afternoon, I don't understand English much, but I will try to express and make clear a problem that I have and I couldn't solve even with chatgpt.

I have a billing project, I have an error when adding bonus items to another item. example: item: paneton, I add 2 bonuses sugar and milk, these are bonus type: in view e it shows paneton, milk and milk, it should show me paneton, sugar and milk, I have a problem in the loop handling the item model I can't solve it here is the extract of my view in vue js:

```
reChangeItem(bonus_items, random_key, qty = 1) {
            if (qty < 1) {
                return;
            }

            bonus_items = bonus_items.map((b) => b.item_bonus);
    
            let temp = [...this.items];
            this.items = bonus_items;

            this.temp_qty = qty;

            console.log("bonus_items: ", bonus_items);
            console.log("temp: ", temp);

            bonus_items.forEach((bonus) => {
                let { id } = bonus;
                this.form.item_id = id;
                //console.log("id: ", id);
                //console.log("bonus: ", bonus);
                //console.log("formulario: ", this.form);
                this.changeItem();
                this.clickAddItem(random_key);
            });
            
            this.temp_qty = null;
            this.items = temp;
        },
```

changeItem:

```
async changeItem() {
        this.clearExtraInfoItem()

        this.form.item = _.find(this.items, {'id': this.form.item_id});
        this.form.item = this.setExtraFieldOfitem(this.form.item)
        this.form.item_unit_types = _.find(this.items, {'id': this.form.item_id}).item_unit_types
        this.form.unit_price_value = this.form.item.sale_unit_price;
        this.lots = this.form.item.lots

        this.form.has_igv = this.form.item.has_igv;
        this.form.has_plastic_bag_taxes = this.form.item.has_plastic_bag_taxes;
        this.form.affectation_igv_type_id = this.form.item.sale_affectation_igv_type_id;
        this.form.quantity = 1;
        this.cleanTotalItem();
        this.showListStock = true


        //asignar variables isc
        this.form.has_isc = this.form.item.has_isc
        this.form.percentage_isc = this.form.item.percentage_isc
        this.form.system_isc_type_id = this.form.item.system_isc_type_id


        if (this.hasAttributes()) {
            const contex = this
            this.form.item.attributes.forEach((row) => {

                contex.form.attributes.push({
                    attribute_type_id: row.attribute_type_id,
                    description: row.description,
                    value: row.value,
                    start_date: row.start_date,
                    end_date: row.end_date,
                    duration: row.duration,
                })
            })
        }

        this.form.lots_group = this.form.item.lots_group
        this.setExtraElements(this.form.item);

        this.has_list_prices = false;
        if (this.form.item.name_product_pdf && this.config.item_name_pdf_description) {
            this.form.name_product_pdf = this.form.item.name_product_pdf;
        }

        this.addDescriptionToDocumentItem()

        this.getLastPriceItem()

    },
```

clickAddItem:

```
async clickAddItem()
    {
        console.log(this.form);
        if(this.isRestrictedForSale) return this.$message.error('No puede agregar el producto, está restringido para venta.')

        if (this.applyValidateStock()) {
            const validate_current_stock = await this.validateCurrentStock()
            if (!validate_current_stock.success) return this.$message.error(validate_current_stock.message)
        }

        if(this.config.condition_sale_purchase_price_to_item) {
            if (this.form.unit_price_value < this.form.item.purchase_unit_value) return this.$message.error('El Precio Unitario debe ser mayor o igual al costo de compra');
        }


        if (this.isNoteErrorDescription) {
            if (parseFloat(this.form.unit_price_value) < 0) return this.$message.error('El Precio Unitario debe ser mayor o igual 0');
        } else {
            if (parseFloat(this.form.unit_price_value) <= 0) return this.$message.error('El Precio Unitario debe ser mayor a 0');
        }

        // if(this.form.quantity < this.getMinQuantity()){
        //     return this.$message.error(`La cantidad no puede ser inferior a ${this.getMinQuantity()}`);
        // }
        this.validateQuantity()

        if (this.form.item.lots_enabled) {
            if (!this.form.IdLoteSelected)
                return this.$message.error('Debe seleccionar lote.');
        }
        let extra = this.form.item.extra

        if (this.validateTotalItem().total_item) return;

        let affectation_igv_type_id = this.form.affectation_igv_type_id
        // let unit_price = (this.form.has_igv) ? this.form.unit_price_value : this.form.unit_price_value * 1.18;
        let unit_price = this.form.unit_price_value;
        if (this.form.has_igv === false) {
            if (
                affectation_igv_type_id === "20" ||
                affectation_igv_type_id === "21" ||
                affectation_igv_type_id === "40"
            ) {
                // do nothing
                // exonerado de igv
            } else {
                unit_price = this.form.unit_price_value * (1 + this.percentageIgv);

            }
        }


        //validar precio compra y venta
        if (this.configuration) {
            if (this.configuration.validate_purchase_sale_unit_price) {
                let val_purchase_unit_price = parseFloat(this.form.item.purchase_unit_price)

                if (val_purchase_unit_price > parseFloat(unit_price)) {
                    return this.$message.error(`El precio de compra no puede ser superior al precio de venta (P. Compra: ${val_purchase_unit_price})`)
                }
            }
        }


        this.form.input_unit_price_value = this.form.unit_price_value;

        this.form.unit_price = unit_price;
        this.form.item.unit_price = unit_price;
        this.form.item.presentation = this.item_unit_type;
        this.form.affectation_igv_type = _.find(this.affectation_igv_types, {'id': affectation_igv_type_id});

        let IdLoteSelected = this.form.IdLoteSelected
        let document_item_id = this.form.document_item_id
        this.row = calculateRowItem(this.form, this.currencyTypeIdActive, this.exchangeRateSale, this.percentageIgv);

        this.row.item.name_product_pdf = this.row.name_product_pdf || '';
        if (this.recordItem) {
            this.row.indexi = this.recordItem.indexi
        }

        let select_lots = await _.filter(this.row.item.lots, {'has_sale': true})
        let un_select_lots = await _.filter(this.row.item.lots, {'has_sale': false})

        if (this.form.item.series_enabled) {
            if (select_lots.length != this.form.quantity)
                return this.$message.error('La cantidad de series seleccionadas son diferentes a la cantidad a vender');
        }

        //xxxxxxxxxx
        let { has_bonus_item, bonus_items } = this.form.item;
        //this.row.sizes_selected = this.sizes;
        let general_random_key = null;
        if (has_bonus_item) {
            let random_key = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
            this.row.random_key = random_key;
            general_random_key = random_key;
        }
        // this.row.depend_key = this.form.item.depend_key;
        //si key no es nulo y es string
        //xxxxxxxxxx

        // this.row.edit = false;
        this.initForm();
        this.row.item.extra = extra;
        //this.initializeFields()

        if (this.recordItem) {
            this.row.indexi = this.recordItem.indexi
        }

        this.row.IdLoteSelected = IdLoteSelected
        this.row.document_item_id = document_item_id

        this.showMessageDetraction()

        this.$emit('add', this.row);

        if (this.search_item_by_barcode) {
            this.cleanItems()
        }
        if (has_bonus_item) {
            this.reChangeItem(bonus_items, general_random_key,this.row.quantity);
        }
        if (this.recordItem) {
            this.close();
        } else {
            this.setFocusSelectItem();
        }
    },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HOc8.png)

Comment: As a sidenote: Mutating function parameters is rarely a good approach.

Comment: saying what should happen in the UI doesn't help us understand the code because we have no understanding of how the UI relates to the code. things like "item", "milk" and "sugar", are these objects? properties of objects? show actual example values for things like `bonus_items` and explain what things like `this.items` means, and what is the purpose of the loop you say is giving you trouble?  `this.changeItem`, `this.clickAddItem` contain logic we know nothing about.